# What do the functions in the picture mean?

Tags: matlab, maximum-principle

I'm a freelancer coder and I was coding some equations. But for the equation below, I don't know what they mean? can anybody help me so I can model it?

$$\large\delta^*=\arg\{\underset{\delta}{\max}E[B(WA)-L(F,D)]\}$$

Comment: What are $E,B,W $ and $A$, are they functions of $\delta$? I'm guessing $arg$ means the complex argument, i.e the angle of a complex number and the positive real axis measured counter clockwise maybe? We need more context.

Comment: My guess: $B(WA) - L(F,D)$ is an expression which involves some random variables and depends on parameter $\delta$.
$E[B(WA)-L(F,D)]$ is its [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) which depends on $\delta$ implicitly. $\arg\{\max_\delta(\cdots)\}$ is the value of $\delta$ which maximizes this $\delta$-dependent expected value. (see wiki entry of [arg max](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max)).

Comment: @achillehui yes, your guesses are right, and your comment made it clearer for me. Thanks alot

Comment: Thanks for @NoelLundström too for his/her consideration

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is not immediately apparent, the expression $E[B(WA)-L(F,D)]$ seems to be a function of $\delta$. Now $\max_\delta$ describes the maximal "output" that this expression can attain among all possible choices of $\delta$, and $\operatorname{arg}$ describes an "input" that produces this maximal "output". In other words, $\delta^*$ is a *maximizer* of $E[B(WA)-L(F,D)]$.

Comment: Thanks. It is clearer now. Thanks a lot